# Using daemontools with a Python script that spawns subprocesses

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, daemon

I am trying to set up [daemontools](http://thedjbway.b0llix.net/daemontools.html) with a large python program that spawns various subprocesses, and I'm having issues where the subprocesses are not spawning correctly. The subprocess just appears as a zombified process when launched via daemontools.

I have provided a simplified example to demonstrate this.

/service/test/run:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /script_directory/
exec envdir /service/test/env /usr/bin/python3 test_subprocess.py
```

/script_directory/test_subprocess.py

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep
subprocess.Popen("xterm")
while True:
    sleep(1)
```

test_subprocess.py simply launches a GUI terminal and stays alive, so I can see if it is still running in top/htop.
If I run the script either as root or a non-root user, the script properly executes and the window is displayed. When run via daemontools/supervise, the xterm is zombified and no window is shown. 
Setting the env/DISPLAY and env/XAUTHORITY variables as described [here](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/djbdns/daemontools_intro.htm#pro_troubleshooting_move_the_xtermd_service) doesn't seem to work for me.

On further investigation, the subprocess is zombified even if it does not use the GUI. For example if the subprocess in subprocess.py is "top" - it will not run.

I've used daemontools successfully on various other projects that don't spawn subprocesses so I don't think the issue is with the basic setup here.

**Can daemontools be used with scripts that spawn other processes?**

If not, what some other recommended tools for daemonising complex python applications?

Comment: My guess is that you're missing environment variables like PATH. For supervisor, see http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment

Comment: Alternatively, you could fully specify the path to `xterm`

Comment: You tried http://supervisord.org/ yet ?

Comment: I'll try switching to supervisord and report back

Comment: I've just switched to supervisord and it's able to launch my python scripts _and_ the subprocesses launched from python. Seems much easier to set up and get working!

Answer (score -1):

bro i can't understand what you went to do. but try this program:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(
['xterm', '-hold'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```

if went to give some argument use -e and type command,and if another problem please let me know.thanks

Comment: Not my dv but if you don't understand what the OP is trying to do what are you answering the question for?

Comment: Sorry, this is irrelevant to the problem here. It has been resolved by switching from daemontools to supervisord.